# What is a good way to break vulkan to test if a debug callback was setup properly?

Tags: c++, debugging, vulkan

I am learning vulkan for the first time, and I am on step 2 of the [vulkan tutorial](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Setup/Validation_layers). Drawing a triangle->Setup->Validation layers.

I did the setup for the error callback, and now I want to test that it actually works (I couldn't get any error messages).

I have checked that all of my functions are getting called (the only one that doesn't print anything is the debugCallBack itself).

It seems nothing is broken. How can I break things to test whether the error callback is setup properly?

If this was OpenGL I would try to setup a random uniform name in the standard program (0) for example.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reported this particular problem in https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Loader/issues/123.

In the meantime I do two things:

1) I use `vkDebugReportMessageEXT` resp. `vkSubmitDebugUtilsMessageEXT` to print an intro message. That shows the debug callback works.

2) Easy way to break validation is `vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices( instance, nullptr, nullptr );`

Comment: I am a total noob in regards to Vulkan, how exactly did you use `vkDebugReportMessageEXT`?

Tip 2 worked like a charm tho

Comment: @Makogan First you need to load it with e.g. `PFN_vkDebugReportMessageEXT myvkDebugReportMessageEXT = (PFN_vkDebugReportMessageEXT)vkGetInstanceProcAddr( instance, "vkDebugReportMessageEXT" );` then it is relatively self-explanatory, you call e.g.: `myvkDebugReportMessageEXT( instance, VK_DEBUG_REPORT_PERFORMANCE_WARNING_BIT_EXT, VK_DEBUG_REPORT_OBJECT_TYPE_INSTANCE_EXT, (uint64_t)instance, __LINE__, 0, "Application", "Hello debug callback" );` Which calls your registered debug callback(s) through the extensions mechanisms with pretty much the identical parameters as provided to the command.

Answer (score 1):

I've been following a different tutorial; however, I have a set of files `Validation.h` and `Validation.cpp` that are used for `Vulkan's` `ValidationLayers` They are quite simple as they contain just a standalone function. The files for use of the `ValidationLayers` look like this:

*-Validation.h-*

```
#pragma once

#include <vulkan\vulkan.h>

void ErrorCheck( VkResult res );
```

*-Validation.cpp-*

```
#include "Validation.h"

#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>

void ErrorCheck( VkResult res ) {
    if ( res != VK_SUCCESS ) {
        std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
        assert( 0 && "There Was An Error" );
    }
}
```

This is just a simple function to print out the messages to the console and to assert that there was an error. The actual `ValidationLayers` resides in a different location which will be shown below.

---

Now to setup the `Validation Layers` I have a class called `VulkanInstance`. The class looks like this:

*-VulkanInstance.h-*

```
#pragma once

#include "VulkanConfiguration.h"

#include <vector>
#include <vulkan\vulkan.h>

class VulkanInstance {
private:
    VkInstance m_instance;
    std::vector<const char*> m_layers;
    std::vector<const char*> m_extensions;

public:
    VulkanInstance( VulkanConfiguration& vulkan_config );
    ~VulkanInstance();

    VkInstance& getInstance();
};
```

*-VulkanInstance.cpp-*

```
#include "VulkanInstance.h"

#include "Validation.h"
#include "Initializers.h"

#include <iostream>

VulkanInstance::VulkanInstance( VulkanConfiguration& vulkan_config ) {
    m_layers.push_back("VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation");
    m_extensions.push_back("VK_EXT_debug_report");

    VkApplicationInfo application_info = Initializers::applicationInfo( vulkan_config );
    VkInstanceCreateInfo instance_info = Initializers::instanceCreateInfo( application_info, m_layers, m_extensions );
    ErrorCheck( vkCreateInstance( &instance_info, NULL, &m_instance ) );
}

VulkanInstance::~VulkanInstance() {
    vkDestroyInstance( m_instance, NULL );
}

VkInstance& VulkanInstance::getInstance() {
    return m_instance;
}
```

Since this class above does have a couple of dependency I will show you `VulkanConfiguration` and `Initializers`. `VulkanConfiguration` is a header only and `Initializers` is a bunch of standalone functions for creating `Vulkan` type objects wrapped in a `namespace`. I will show the full `Initializers` header but I will only show the relevant function declarations that are needed for the `ValidationLayers` and the `VulkanInstance`.

---

*-VulkanConfiguration.h-*

```
#pragma once

#include <vulkan\vulkan.h>

struct VulkanConfiguration {
    const char* application_name = "";
    uint32_t application_version = VK_MAKE_VERSION( 0, 0, 0 );
    const char* engine_name = "My Vulkan Engine";
    const uint32_t engine_version = VK_MAKE_VERSION( 0, 0, 0 );
    const uint32_t api_version = VK_MAKE_VERSION( 1, 1, 82 );
};
```

---

*-Initializers.h-*

```
#pragma once

#include <vulkan\vulkan.h>
#include <vector>

struct VulkanConfiguration;

namespace Initializers {    
    VkApplicationInfo applicationInfo( VulkanConfiguration& config );
    VkInstanceCreateInfo instanceCreateInfo( VkApplicationInfo& app_info, std::vector<const char*>& layers, std::vector<const char*>& extensions );
    VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo deviceQueueCreateInfo( uint32_t queue_family_index, float& priority );
    VkDeviceCreateInfo deviceCreateInfo( std::vector<VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo>& queue_create_infos, VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures& device_features );
    VkCommandPoolCreateInfo commandPoolCreateInfo( uint32_t queue_family_index, VkCommandPoolCreateFlags flags = 0 );
    VkCommandBufferAllocateInfo commandBufferAllocateInfo( VkCommandPool pool, uint32_t count );
    VkBufferCreateInfo bufferCreate( VkDeviceSize size, VkBufferUsageFlags usage );
    VkMemoryAllocateInfo memoryAllocateInfo( VkDeviceSize size, uint32_t memory_type_index );
}
```

*-Intializers.cpp-*

```
#include "Initializers.h"
#include "VulkanConfiguration.h"

VkApplicationInfo Initializers::applicationInfo( VulkanConfiguration& config ) {
    VkApplicationInfo info = {};
    info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_APPLICATION_INFO;
    info.pApplicationName = config.application_name;
    info.pEngineName = config.engine_name;
    info.applicationVersion = config.application_version;
    info.engineVersion = config.engine_version;
    info.apiVersion = config.api_version;
    return info;
}

VkInstanceCreateInfo Initializers::instanceCreateInfo( VkApplicationInfo& app_info, std::vector<const char*>& layers, std::vector<const char*>& extensions ) {
    VkInstanceCreateInfo info = {};
    info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
    info.pApplicationInfo = &app_info;
    info.enabledExtensionCount = extensions.size();
    info.enabledLayerCount = layers.size();
    info.ppEnabledExtensionNames = extensions.data();
    info.ppEnabledLayerNames = layers.data();
    return info;
}
```

This should give us everything we need for our `ValidationLayers` to be setup.

---

Now to get Vulkan fully running you do need `VulkanDevice`, `VulkanPhysicalDevice` and `QueueFamilyIndices`, however I'm sure that since you are probably already rendering a triangle you should have them in place. To demonstrate how to get the `ValidationLayers` to work I will show you the constructor and destructor to the `VulkanDevice` class...

*-VulkanDevice.cpp-*  -- Partial source code

```
#include "VulkanDevice.h"

#include "Initializers.h"
#include "Validation.h"
#include "VulkanPhysicalDevice.h"

#include <vector>

VulkanDevice::VulkanDevice( VulkanInstance* instance, VulkanPhysicalDevice* physical_device ) {
    m_instance = instance;
    m_vulkan_physical_device = physical_device;

    std::vector<VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo> queue_create_infos;
    float priority = 1.0f;
    queue_create_infos.push_back( Initializers::deviceQueueCreateInfo( m_vulkan_physical_device->getQueueFamilyIndices().compute_indices, priority ) );

    VkDeviceCreateInfo create_info = Initializers::deviceCreateInfo( queue_create_infos, m_vulkan_physical_device->getPhysicalDeviceFeatures() );

    ErrorCheck( vkCreateDevice(
        m_vulkan_physical_device->getPhysicalDevice(),
        &create_info,
        nullptr,
        &m_device
    ) );

    vkGetDeviceQueue(
        m_device,
        m_vulkan_physical_device->getQueueFamilyIndices().compute_indices,
        0,
        &m_compute_queue
    );

    VkCommandPoolCreateInfo compute_pool_info = Initializers::commandPoolCreateInfo( m_vulkan_physical_device->getQueueFamilyIndices().compute_indices );

    ErrorCheck( vkCreateCommandPool(
        m_device,
        &compute_pool_info,
        nullptr,
        &m_compute_command_pool
    ) );
}

VulkanDevice::~VulkanDevice() {
    vkDestroyCommandPool(
        m_device,
        m_compute_command_pool,
        nullptr
    );

    vkDestroyDevice(
        m_device,
        nullptr
    );
}
```

Here you can see that in the constructor I am calling `vkCreateDevice()` and `vkCreateCommandPool()` within the free function `ErrorCheck()`. As of right now, my code base when I compile and run it, it returns with an value of 0 and no errors. However, in the destructor to this class; if I comment out either of the `vkDestroy...` functions, either  for the `CommandPool` or the `Device`:

```
VulkanDevice::~VulkanDevice() {
    /*
    vkDestroyCommandPool(
        m_device,
        m_compute_command_pool,
        nullptr
    );
    */

    vkDestroyDevice(
        m_device,
        nullptr
    );
}
```

or

```
VulkanDevice::~VulkanDevice() {
    vkDestroyCommandPool(
        m_device,
        m_compute_command_pool,
        nullptr
    );

    /*
    vkDestroyDevice(
        m_device,
        nullptr
    );
    */
}
```

It will give me these printed messages to the console respectively:

```
VUID-vkDestroyDevice-device-00378(ERROR / SPEC): msgNum: 614466292 - OBJ ERROR : For device 0x42af310, CommandPool objec
t 0x1 has not been destroyed. The spec valid usage text states 'All child objects created on device must have been destr
oyed prior to destroying device' (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/html/vkspec.html#VUID-vkDestroyDevic
e-device-00378)
    Objects: 1
       [0] 0x1, type: 25, name: (null)
Validation(ERROR): msg_code: 614466292:  [ VUID-vkDestroyDevice-device-00378 ]  [ VUID-vkDestroyDevice-device-00378 ] Ob
ject: 0x1 (Type = 25) | OBJ ERROR : For device 0x42af310, CommandPool object 0x1 has not been destroyed. The spec valid
usage text states 'All child objects created on device must have been destroyed prior to destroying device' (https://www
.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/html/vkspec.html#VUID-vkDestroyDevice-device-00378)

C:\Users\...\Vulkan Tutorial.exe (process 1256) exited w
ith code 0.
To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the conso
le when debugging stops.
Press any key to close this window . . .
```

And

```
UNASSIGNED-ObjectTracker-ObjectLeak(ERROR / SPEC): msgNum: -1 - OBJ ERROR : VK_DEBUG_REPORT_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE_EXT objec
t 0x4139590 has not been destroyed.
    Objects: 1
       [0] 0x4139590, type: 3, name: (null)
Validation(ERROR): msg_code: -1:  [ UNASSIGNED-ObjectTracker-ObjectLeak ]  [ UNASSIGNED-ObjectTracker-ObjectLeak ] Objec
t: 0x4139590 (Type = 3) | OBJ ERROR : VK_DEBUG_REPORT_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE_EXT object 0x4139590 has not been destroyed.

C:\Users\...\Vulkan Tutorial.exe (process 2480) exited w
ith code 0.
To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the conso
le when debugging stops.
Press any key to close this window . . .
```

---

Hopefully this will give you some insight into the workings of Vulkan and its ValidationLayers in a general sense. The code above is not my own as it came from an online tutorial from [this](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCMy_zy0dw4fCfs2cL7UPBQA) Youtube channel.